# botskills connect: 'Failed importing latest version of virtualassistanten_Dispatch app'

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I am following the tutorial by Microsoft to create a virtual assistant chatbot with multiple bots, i.e. skills stitched together. I am trying to [register a sample skill to a virtual assistant bot](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/tutorials/csharp/addingprebuiltskills.md) on Azure by running

> botskills connect

but I get an error when importing the dispatch luis app virtualassistantboten_Dispatch as shown below.

> Updating virtualassistantboten_Dispatch model...
>   Training virtualassistantboten_general…
>   Importing virtualassistantboten_Dispatch model...
>
> ERROR
>   Failed importing latest version of virtualassistantboten_Dispatch app

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: I tried this with another skill, the Calendar skill and it went fine, no error. This error happened when I was trying to register the ToDo skill with the VA. But unfortunately I still have not been able to identify what the root cause is.

Comment: Refer to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/issues/1949) issue on GitHub which is similar to the error you are getting for ToDo Skill due to the ludown tool.

Comment: If I use an older version of ludown I might not get the error. If I downgrade from version 1.3.2 to 1.3.1 and retry I get the error Update available 1.3.1 -> 1.3.2. [This commit](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/pull/2021/commits/2bbfec412ce001adf6631e3e301e75968199cf1e#diff-1b5c663f2f2ceac84299d81e37be8e7d) in Botskills lets you run botskills command without getting the "Update Available" error. But then how do I incorporate that? I did an npm install of Botskills to update it but that change was not reflected. Will I need to wait for the next publish of Botskills CLI?

Comment: It is a known issue that ludown v1.3.2 fails to parse pattern entities and this should be fixed in v1.3.3. Please use npm install -g ludown@1.3.1 to downgrade.

Comment: How can I get botskills to work with the downgrade?

Comment: Run npm install -g botskills --registry https://botbuilder.myget.org/F/aitemplates/npm/